# Replace query string with '/' via .htaccess file

Tags: php, string, .htaccess, url, replace

http://thewebsitedemo.com/Just-dial/Chandigarh.php?categories=hotel&searchkeyword=tamarind

I have above url after form submitted. I want to replace query string static variables with '/'.

eg. I need url like this:
http://thewebsitedemo.com/Just-dial/Chandigarh/hotel/tamarind

Comment: Tried with url and mod rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+Just-dial/Chandigarh\.php\?categories=([^&]+)&searchkeyword=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /Just-dial/Chandigarh/%1/%2? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^Just-dial/Chandigarh/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /Just-dial/Chandigarh.php?categories=$1&searchkeyword=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Results are not displaying after changing URL with .htacess file